# Windows 7 Hangs. Is there anyway to bring up Task Manager?

Tags: windows-7

I'm running Windows 7 (32-bit) as a development workstation.  Either software I've installed today (SQL Server 2008) or new software I'm working on and testing with NUnit is causing the Windows 7 shell to lockup.  Windows Explorer windows will show the "(Not Responding)" message in the title bar.  Occasionally some windows will remain slightly responsive (like a remote desktop session to corporate office systems).

I'm not able to right-click on the task bar or CTL-ALT-DEL to bring up Task Manager.  There's no evidence in the event logs to suggest what is actually happening.  At present the only solution to deal with the event is to power cycle the system.  I'd prefer not to do that.

Is there anyway to bring up Task Manager in Windows 7 when the the task bar and CTL-ALT-DEL are not responding?  If so, how?

**Update**:  Using Mathieu's suggestion, I brought up SysInternals' ProcessExplorer before running the tests.  When the tests completed and I tried to close NUnit I saw that the window closed.  The NUnit process stayed running.  Other windows, like Windows Explorer, were once again frozen.  Trying to kill the NUnit process with ProcessExplorer caused ProcessExplorer to hang.  So, clearly, it is some of the code that is under test that is causing NUnit to not exit cleanly.

Now if I could just get the system back to a functioning state without having to power cycle ...

Comment: You misunderstood Mathieu's suggestion. You used Process Explorer, which is a great tool, but he had suggested that you use Process Monitor (also from Sysinternals), which will give you much more granular information and you may find out what in the code is locking you up.

Comment: Fair enough.  I did download ProcesMonitor, set it to capture events just before closing NUnit, and began watching it.  When the NUnit window disappeared from the screen I went to ProcessMonitor to see what happened.  ProcessMonitor locked up.

Answer (score 1):

Any luck with Win + R to bring up Run, then if so try to launch "taskmgr" that way.

If you have a working explorer window, use "C:\WINDOWS\system32\taskmgr.exe"

but outside of these two options, Right Click -> Task Manager, CTRL+ALT+DEL and CTRL+SHIFT+ESC you can't do much more.

Comment: I haven't tried Win+R in this context.  The shell has been unresponsive, so I would expect that it wouldn't work either.  I'll endeavor to try it as I work through this.

Comment: Win+R does not work.  :(

Comment: That is a shame :( options are limited after that. Really not much more you can do beyond the methods I listed above.

Answer (score 0):

you could use ctrl + shift +esc

but i guess it won't work better, as even the sas sequence is not working.

You could either use process monitor from sysinternal (launched before the hand) or enable the crashOnControl to get a memory dump and so find what's hanging the system that way

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill, but if you're comfortable with kernel dumps you can [force a blue screen memory dump from the keyboard](http://msmvps.com/blogs/kernelmustard/archive/2005/06/14/52865.aspx) and then look at the memory dump file...